# Swift - How to get the index when a button is selected in a menu

Tags: swift, xcode, button, indexing, menu

I have made a menu with buttons. When the button is selected I would like to pass the index of the button selected to a function to do a calculation. I am able to get the value of the button selected, but can't get an hold on the index value. I am new in Swift and am stuck at this moment. Must be an easy thing, out can't find the solution yet. See the picture below:

[image]

In the code below I would like to pass the index (integer) in the following statement:

```
ContentView.displayDate = myPict.myFirstDayMonth (maand: gekozenMaand)
```

The code:

```
let hoofdstukTabel = [" 1 - Impact", " 2 - Change", " 3 - Portfolio", " 4 - Innovation", " 5 - Analysis", " 6 - Digital", " 7 - Effectiveness", " 8 - Sport & Fun", " 9 - Strategy", "10 - Structure", "11 - Value", "12 - Management"]

        var body: some View {
            
            VStack {
            
                Menu {
                    ForEach(hoofdstukTabel, id: \.self) { action in
                       Button(action) {
                       let gekozenMaand = "\(action)"
                       ContentView.displayDate = myPict.myFirstDayMonth (maand: gekozenMaand)
                       curDate = myPict.myPicture()
                       }
                    }
                } label: {
                        Label(myPict.myChapter(), systemImage: "diamond")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an enumerated sequence to get the index and the string for each element.

```swift
ForEach(Array(hoofdstukTabel.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, action in
    // your content
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. Works like charm!